# sql trae solo id excepto cuando los coloco directamente en el controlador

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Tengo una pagina "welcome" que es mi pagina de inicio, dentro de ella tengo un `href-editar` que esta en el `td` de mi pagina.

Al hacer click me arroja el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nombre' cannot be null (SQL: update `ejemplo` set `nombre` = ?, `categoria` = ?, `descripcion` = ? where `id` = 2) no me trae datos excepto cuando en el controlador los coloco  directamente no con el request.

Siendo que tengo en la vista editar el metodo PUT como

```
@method='PUT'
```

**Vista Editar**

```
@if(session('mensaje'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('mensaje')}}</div>
@endif
<form method="POST" action="{{route('update',$notas->id)}}" >
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

    @error('nombre')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            el nombre es obligatorio
        </div>
    @enderror

    @error('categoria')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            la categoria es obligatoria
        </div>
    @enderror

    @error('descripcion')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                la descripcion es obligatoria
    </div>
    @enderror
    <input
        type="text"
        name="nombre"
        placeholder="Nombre"
        class="form-control mb-2"
        value="{{$notas->nombre}}">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="categoria"
        placeholder="Categoria"
        class="form-control mb-2"
        value="{{$notas->categoria}}">
    <input
        type="text"
        name="descripcion"
        placeholder="Descripcion"
        class="form-control mb-2"
        value="{{$notas->descripcion}}">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">actualizar</button>
</form>
```

**Vista Welcome**

```
<td>
    <a href="{{route('update',$it->id)}}">editar</a>
    <form action="{{ route('eliminar', $it) }}" class="d-inline" method="POST">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <button class="btn btn-danger" btn-sm type="submit">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::put('/update/{pk}','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@update')->name('update');
```

**Controlador**

```
public function update(Request $request,$pk){
    $notas=ejemplo::find($pk);
    $notas->nombre=$request->nombre;
    $notas->categoria=$request->categoria;
    $notas->descripcion=$request->descripcion;

    $notas->save();
    //return view ('editar',compact('notas'));
    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Nota actualizada!');
}
```

Comment: El href editar de la vista welcome `<a href="{{route('update',$it->id)}}">editar</a>` te estás refiriendo a la ruta que tiene método `put`, pero debería referirse a una ruta `get` que te devuelva la vista con el formulario.

Comment: editado route::get

Comment: Te sugiero que, primero que nada, en el controlador valides el request entrante `$validated = $request->validate([  'nombre' => 'required|string',  'categoria' => 'required|string',  'descripcion' => 'required|string', ]);`